# How to put multiple models on the same page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

> I'm doing a website in html and base (where all pages extend) I want
> to put a session of social network icons. As this session is base on
> html it should be displayed on all pages of the website.
>
> I do not want
> to put this session in a static html, I want to do in django using
> models. This is already done.

**Question**: Do I have to put the session of social network icons on each view, or can I make a separate view and all others extend this view?
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).  You can create a function for doing all of the work to create the sessions and then associate that with a particular block of HTML.

**templatetags/session.py**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('includes/session_box.html')
def output_session_box(...):
    ...
    return { .. }
```

The associated template file, **includes/session_box.html**, would have the HTML like any template.

And then your **base.html** would have:

```
{% load session %}
{%  output_session_box ... %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RequestContext` and a `context_processor` to inject template variables into every view using `RequestContext`.

It's as simple as a python function accepting `request` as an arg, and returning a dictionary to be passed into your template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext

```
def my_processor(request):
    return {'foo': 'bar'}

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     # add path to your context processor here.
)
```

I generally have a per-project processor for the basics... It's exactly how django adds `{{ user }}` or `{{ STATIC_URL }}` to every template.